# Disable button untill dropdown item is selected in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to enable the submit button when any item is selected in dropdown.
Here is the code. There are 2 buttons when the user selects from the dropdown the 2 buttons should be enabled. Otherwise it has to be disbled until item is selected from dropdown. Whether any jquery plugin has to be added?

```
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


$(document).ready(function() {


    $(".nextbutton").attr("disabled", true);
     $(".nextbutton1").attr("disabled", true);
    $('.dropdown').change(function() {
        if ($('.dropdown').val() == 0) {
                    $(".nextbutton").attr("disabled", true);
                $(".nextbutton1").attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
                    $(".nextbutton").attr("disabled", false);
                $(".nextbutton1").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});</script>
 </head>

  <body>
<form id="phonetypeform">
      <select name="porting-p1" class="dropdown">
<option value="" class="disablenext">Please select an option...</option>
<option value="1" class="enablenext">I want to keep my current phone number</option>
<option value="2" class="enablenext">I want to choose a new number</option>
        </select>

</form>
<button class="nextbutton1">sd Step</button> 
<button class="nextbutton">Next Step</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see i get errors when i just took your code verbatim and running it, please next time also open developer console as i can see there lot of errors that you probably could have picked up, try this:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".nextbutton").prop('disabled',true);
     $(".nextbutton1").prop('disabled',true);
    $('.dropdown').change(function() {
        if ($('.dropdown').val() == 0) {
          $(".nextbutton").prop('disabled',true);
           $(".nextbutton1").prop('disabled',true);
        } else {
          $(".nextbutton").prop('disabled',false);
           $(".nextbutton1").prop('disabled',false);
        }
    });

});</script>
 </head>

  <body>
<form id="phonetypeform">
      <select name="porting-p1" class="dropdown">
<option value="" class="disablenext">Please select an option...</option>
<option value="1" class="enablenext">1</option>
<option value="2" class="enablenext">2</option>
        </select>

</form>
<button class="nextbutton1">sd Step</button> 
<button class="nextbutton">Next Step</button>
```

Comment: I the above snippet it is working fine. If i copy paste the same code.. It is not working..

Comment: edited, it seems it was unable to get jquery from: //code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js....i changed https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js and tested it off StackOverflow, and it works...please try again

Answer (score 0):

Are you using jquery UI? Because if not, button() does nothing. Try the simple attr:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.nextbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.nextbutton1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('.dropdown').change(function () {
        if ($('.dropdown').val() == 0) {
            $('.nextbutton').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
            $('.nextbutton1').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $('.nextbutton').removeAttr('disabled');
            $('.nextbutton1').removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: jquery UI is an extension to jquery: [link](https://jqueryui.com/) But it's not required here, I was just asking. You can add/remove the disabled attribute by calling attr('disabled', 'disabled') or removeAttr('disabled') on the buttons, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Change your javascript to this instead:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


    $(".nextbutton").attr("disabled", true);
     $(".nextbutton1").attr("disabled", true);
    $('.dropdown').change(function() {
        if ($('.dropdown').val() == 0) {
                    $(".nextbutton").attr("disabled", true);
                $(".nextbutton1").attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
                    $(".nextbutton").attr("disabled", false);
                $(".nextbutton1").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

disabled is an attribute

Comment: maybe try moving the script from your head to your body

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine in snippet.
I assume you are having more than one dropdown in you actual code.
If so change your selector to unique and use `$(this)` to value.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


    $(".nextbutton").attr("disabled", true);
     $(".nextbutton1").attr("disabled", true);
    $('.dropdown[name=porting-p1]').change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == 0) {
                    $(".nextbutton").attr("disabled", true);
                $(".nextbutton1").attr("disabled", true);
        } else {
                    $(".nextbutton").attr("disabled", false);
                $(".nextbutton1").attr("disabled", false);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="phonetypeform">
      <select name="porting-p1" class="dropdown">
<option value="" class="disablenext">Please select an option...</option>
<option value="1" class="enablenext">I want to keep my current phone number</option>
<option value="2" class="enablenext">I want to choose a new number</option>
        </select>

</form>
<button class="nextbutton1">sd Step</button> 
<button class="nextbutton">Next Step</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is actually working. I just need to change it to use jquery 1.12.4 from google CDN.

Apart from that, you can disable both buttons by default on page load by adding `disabled` attribute to both buttons. This will make sure the buttons are disabled from the first time they are rendered. And also provide a class name that will be the same for both buttons, so you only need to call a line of code to disable or enable. If you need a unique identifier for each of the button, you can put `nextbutton1` and `nextbutton2` as the id for each of the button. And last, instead of checking on change event to the form, you can make it listen to the dropdown directly. Therefore it will only be triggered if the change occurs on the dropdown.

```
<head>      
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#dropdownNumber').change(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == 0) {
                    $(".nextbutton").attr("disabled", true);
                 } else {
                    $(".nextbutton").attr("disabled", false);
                 }
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="phonetypeform">
        <select name="porting-p1" class="dropdown" id="dropdownNumber">
            <option value="" class="disablenext">Please select an option...</option>
            <option value="1" class="enablenext">I want to keep my current phone number</option>
            <option value="2" class="enablenext">I want to choose a new number</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <button class="nextbutton" id="nextbutton1" disabled>sd Step</button> 
    <button class="nextbutton" id="nextbutton2" disabled>Next Step</button> 
</body>
```